# parallax with nested tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

im tring to develop app.. its have a profile page... i want to make this page like profile in [Google+](https://itunes.apple.com/sa/app/google+/id447119634?mt=8) app in ios...

its parallax with table view... but its have a segment to transfer between 3 chooses...

i found a lot of parallax code... but its only 1 parallax view for image and one table view...

so i need to add 3 table view... and transfer between these table.. without lost data or user scrolling of each table...

[parallax open source... maybe i use it in my project](https://github.com/xelvenone/M6ParallaxController?source=c)

example what i need exactly
[image: example]

Comment: If you find answer for this please give a link for sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not sure how it will work out, but you can try to insert the second table view into a cell of the parent table view (probably assign the height of the cell corresponding to the height of the inner table)